# Php 24 Hour Restriction

Tags: php

I'm using this code for one online game called Ragnarok Online. I'm making a script called vote for points, but i want to add a 24 hour time restriction when the user ip matches the ip on database.

My code:

```
mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Pswd) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ($Data) or die ("Bla Bla.");

$Vote = mysql_query("SELECT `last_ip` FROM `vote_por_pontos` WHERE `account_id` = '{$Array['account_id']}'");
$Vote_Result = mysql_fetch_assoc($Vote);

$Vote_Time = mysql_query("SELECT `time` FROM `vote_por_pontos` WHERE `account_id` = '{$Array['account_id']}'");
$Vote_Time_Result = mysql_fetch_assoc($Vote);

if($Vote_Result['last_ip'] == "") {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `vote_por_pontos` (`account_id`, `pontos`, `time`, `last_ip`) VALUES ('{$Array['account_id']}', '1', '".time()."', '$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]')");
    echo "Bla bla";
    exit;
}

if($Vote_Result['last_ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
   if($Vote_Time_Result['time'] > (???)) {
}
```

Field `time` returns epoch time.

```
if($Vote_Result['last_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `vote_por_pontos` SET `pontos` = `pontos` + 1, `last_ip` = '$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]' WHERE `account_id` = '{$Array['account_id']}'");
    echo "Bla bla";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.

Comment: Why don't you get 'last_ip' and 'time' in the same query?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is exactly but based on the leading paragraph, I would say you should do that directly in sql and check the number of affected rows after that if necessary.

Comment: The script is simple.

1) If there's no last ip on tables, then the script insert the values on mysql.
(That's what i need) 2) If the ip on mysql field `last_ip` is equal of ip of the user, then, i need check if the time is > 24 hour and i don't know how to do this.

The inserted time on `time` field is equal epoch time.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code to use mysqli and I've written it so it will make one query to the database to see if the ip address has voted on the account_id in the last 24 hours. If they haven't then do something with it:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli($Host, $User, $Pswd, $Data);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM vote_por_pontos WHERE account_id = ? AND lastip = ? AND `time` >= ?');

$account_id = $Array['account_id'];
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$time       = time() - (24 * 60 * 60); // 24 hours ago

$stmt->bind_param('d', $account_id);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $ip_address);
$stmt->bind_param('d', $time);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($already_voted);
$stmt->fetch();

if (!$already_voted) {
    // This ip address hasn't voted on that account in the last 24 hours
    // TODO something here
}

$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```